# Will Ubuntu Mate desktop 20.04 install on Dell Optiplex 7010

Tags: 20.04, dell, mate

Dell 7010 Optiplex 8gb memory 250 gb ssd

Comment: Why not try before you install?   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   where it works for all Ubuntu *flavors* too

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your hardware.
Read the requirements for Ubuntu Mate: https://ubuntu-mate.org/about/requirements/
You will need to read what hardware your PC has now.

If you see and believe you can install it then install the OS.

Note: You most likely will be able to run it but we can't tell you for sure.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: "Will-it-work?" is precisely why the Ubuntu Mate installer includes a "Try it" environment *before* committing to an install -- so users like the OP can test risk-free.